# How can I pass query param to login page when using spring security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Foremost I have to say that I dont have login page, I have pop-up menu in two pages(index.jsp,registration.jsp), and it pop-up menu will be displayed when attribute is true, so I want to pass query param in login page, but when I do it my UserDetailsService dont be invoked  and I get HTTP Status 405 because method Is not supported but If I don't pass the param It works fine (form login url is /index).

Security configuration :

```
  @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("customUserDetailsService")
        private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    
        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        }
    
        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/pages/user/**").hasRole("CLIENT")
                    .antMatchers("/pages/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("/pages/guest/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/*").permitAll()
                    .and().formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/index?showDialog=true")
                    .permitAll()
                    .usernameParameter("login")
                    .passwordParameter("psw")
                    .and()
                    .logout()
                    .permitAll()
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
        }
    }
```

*Index mapping :*

```
@GetMapping({"/index", "/"})
    public ModelAndView homePage(@RequestParam(value = "showDialog",defaultValue = "false") boolean showDialog) {
        LOGGER.info("HomeAction is invoked");
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("index");
        List<CarCategory> carCategories = carCategoryService.findExistingCarC();
        LOGGER.debug("Get Existing CarCategories, number Is {}", carCategories.size());
        List<Car> cars = carService.findAll();
        LOGGER.debug("Get All Cars , Car number Is {}", cars.size());
        List<Long> counts = carService.findNumberCarByCat();
        modelAndView.addObject("cars", cars);
        modelAndView.addObject("categories", carCategories);
        modelAndView.addObject("counts", counts);
        modelAndView.addObject("showDialog",showDialog);
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

How can I do it in correct way?

Comment: Could you please share the Controller with the mappings for `/index`.

Comment: @EleftheriaStein-Kousathana I have added index mapping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the `loginPage` to a custom value, it will also configure a number of defaults, including the `loginProcessingUrl`.

```java
http
    .formLogin(form -> form
            .loginPage("/index?showDialog=true")
    );
```

In the above example, the `loginProcessingUrl` is also set to "/index?showDialog=true".
This is the URL that you need to POST to in order to validate the user's credentials.

If you wish to use a different URL as the `loginProcessingUrl`, you will have to add it to the configuration.

```
http
    .formLogin(form -> form
            .loginPage("/index?showDialog=true")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/index")
    );
```

In your custom login page you can now POST to "/index" to validate the user's credentials.
For example:

```html
<form th:action="@{/index}" method="post">
    <label for="username">Username</label>:
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/> <br />
    <label for="password">Password</label>:
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" /> <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
</form>
```